# Compress video using cordova-plugin-media-capture

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

Is there any way to compress the video when we capture the video using "cordova-plugin-media-capture" plugin. because when i capture the video for 1 min then the size of video becomes approx 120 mb.

?

Comment: Is there any one who can guide how to compress the video when we capture the video using "cordova-plugin-media-capture" plugin??

Answer (score 1):

Use [`cordova-plugin-video-editor`](https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor).

They have an example in combination with the cordova media capture plugin.

Comment: I have seen cordova-plugin-video-editor but did not find method to compress the video. Can you indicate the method of  cordova-plugin-video-editor for compressing the video?

Comment: The method is [transcodeVideo](https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor#transcode-a-video)

Comment: I've read the transcodeVideo docs, but I didn't find a way to compress the video. Maybe @AntonBiller can have a more detailed answer...

Comment: Transcoding takes lot of time, Ex: to transcode a video of 1 minute, it almost takes 30  seconds. Which is not acceptable in most business. Is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

quality 50% reduced

let options: CaptureVideoOptions = { limit: 1, quality :0.5, duration:60};
this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options)